# Complex MySQL statement to list fishing standings?

Tags: mysql, field, addition

I'm trying to make a standings chart using multiple tables. One keeps tracks of meetings attended to, each meeting counting as 5 points and the other table keeps track of results of tournaments. This is a fishing club site.

I have the following so far and can show the meeting points in order but the tournament results separate from that. I'd like to find a single albeit complex SQL statement to list out current standings.

I need to show the angler name which I can grab separate from a different table, then each month's 5 points listed along with the tournament result amount from the results table, these are all added up to finally list the total from all tournaments and meetings.

```
SELECT aid, sum(here*5) as total 
FROM rollcall GROUP BY aid ORDER BY total DESC

SELECT aid, weight, weight-penalty as fweight 
FROM `results` where tid=2 order by fweight desc
```

So an example is:

```
  place angler  JAN  FEB MARCH ... Total Points

  1 name1 5 50 5 45  0 38       143

  2 name2 5 49 5 47  5 31       142
```

...

Is that clear at all?

Comment: That won't do it. Now, I've added another table to setup points per angler after I edit the results table. It keeps track of the points earned per tournament. Now my problem is joining the rollcall table with the points table to show total points for the standings. My 2 tables have the following.

Comment: aid, here in the rollcall table and aid, points, tid for the points table. When I use 'select points.aid, sum(points) as total from points group by aid order by total desc' it gives the total points per angler in order of highest to lowest. I also use 'select rollcall.aid, sum(here*5) as mtgs from rollcall group by aid order by mtgs desc' to show meeting points. I want to combine the 2 so that it adds the points to the meeting points in desc order for a standings page.

Comment: When I combine them, it comes up with weird math using 'SELECT points.aid, sum( points.points ) AS total, sum( rollcall.here *5 ) AS mtgs FROM `points` , `rollcall` WHERE rollcall.aid = points.aid GROUP BY rollcall.aid ORDER BY total DESC'.

Answer (score 0):

What if you build your query something like this?

```
SELECT aid, 
sum(SELECT count(1) from meetings WHERE MONTH(columndatetime) = 1 * 5) AS JAN,
sum(SELECT count(1) from meetings WHERE MONTH(columndatetime) = 2 * 5) AS FEB,
/
 -- add same logic to the rest of the months
/
sum(SELECT count(1) from meetings WHERE YEAR(columndatetime) = 2013 * 5) as total 
FROM rollcall GROUP BY aid ORDER BY total DESC
```

Where `columndatetime` is the name of your column that has the date and time for the meetings etc...

The last one takes all for the year.

Could this help you out?